# Can Linux Mint's Cinnamon Desktop be installed on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 14.04, cinnamon, mint

I have copied it onto my desktop from a DVD+RW disc. I also have the option to upgrade to 14.04 tho...

Comment: There's no such thing as 'Ubuntu Mint'. Do you mean Linux Mint?

Comment: You mean like virtual machine?  Like running Linux Mint with Ubuntu?  Mint and Ubuntu are pretty similar actually.  I got Mint on another laptop installed,  and visually the difference is only in desktop environment.  You could have Cinnamon desktop in Ubuntu , too, if that the only thing you need.  Under the hood they are very similar

Comment: Cinnamon desktop? Thanks I'll look into it. Think I'll upgrade to 14.04 instead!